# No Event Logs in Diagnostic on Windows Azure?

Tags: .net, diagnostic, remoting, azure

I'm trying to get .NET Remoting to work on Windows Azure, with a web role. I get a 500 internal server error when trying to access the URL. I've tried using Azure MMC (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazuremmc), but I'm only able to get Infrastructure Logs. No Event Logs, Azure Logs or similar. What am I doing wrong? I've tried setting the log level filter to critical, error, warning and even undefined, without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using .NET remoting on Windows Azure - [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnisv/archive/2010/05/31/net-remoting-on-windows-azure.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20140501094757/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnisv/archive/2010/05/31/net-remoting-on-windows-azure.aspx)

Regarding diagnostics, you can check [this nice post](https://convective.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/diagnostics-management-in-windows-azure/) by Neil Mackenzie. Hope it helps.